# Get return of cmd.exe exit

Tags: powershell

I develop a PowerShell application. I use for example

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c some_command"
#rest of the source code
```

But when I run this, it is not waiting for `cmd.exe` to close before executing the rest of the source code.

How can I get `cmd.exe` "exit event" return to continue to run my PowerShell script?

Or other way to sleep PowerShell script while cmd.exe is running?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer is to use `-wait`

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c some_command" -wait
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke CMD directly from PowerShell:

```
cmd.exe /c some_command
```

In case the executable is provided as a string rather than a bare word you must prefix the statement with the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (otherwise using the operator is optional):

```
& 'cmd.exe' /c some_command
```

This kind of invocation automatically runs synchronously.

`Start-Process` invocation is asynchronous by default. You can change the behaviour to synchronous by adding the parameter `-Wait`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `-Wait`, you could also check the exit code to verify command success:

```
[int]$ExitCode = (Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c some_command" -Wait).ExitCode

# Check exit code
if ($ExitCode -ne 0) {
    throw "Something went wrong.
}
```

This is useful for debugging and checking `cmd` success.